# Validar Datos de un fromulario en Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, validación, django-forms

Necesito ayuda en algo, estoy haciendo un sistema académico, la cosa es que necesito asignar una Asignatura a un maestro durante un ciclo escolar 
los registros si se guardan, el problema es que necesito saber como valido para no asignar la la misma Asignatura en el mismo ciclo al mismo maestro 
es decir si los 3 campos que quiero guardar son iguales no los guarde pero si uno de los tres cambia si los guarde, algo mas o menos así: 
(Así debe guardar los registros)

- **Maestro** Juan    **Asignatura Matemáticas**       **Ciclo**  2020
- **Maestro** Pedro   **Asignatura Matemáticas**       **Ciclo**  2020

Pero no así:

- **Maestro** Juan    **Asignatura Matemáticas**       **Ciclo**  2020
- **Maestro** Juan    **Asignatura Matemáticas**       **Ciclo**  2020

---

Intente poniendo `unique=true` en maestro pero no me deja registrar nada mas a ese maestro.

Espero haberme hecho entender y me puedan ayudar.

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Asignar(models.Model):
    docente = models.ForeignKey(Docente, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,unique=True)
    materia = models.ForeignKey(Materia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    periodo = models.ForeignKey(Periodo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.docente, self.materia.nombre, self.periodo)
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
def crear(request):
    f = AsignarForm(request.POST)
    data = {
        'icono': opc_icono, 'ruta': opc_ruta, 'crud': opc_crud
    }
    action = request.POST['action']
    data['action'] = action
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'action' in request.POST:
        if action == 'add':
            f = AsignarForm(request.POST)
        else:
            if f.is_valid():
                f.save()
            else:
                    'form': f
                }
                return render(request, 'back-end/asignar/asignar_form.html', data)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/materia/materias')
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer dicha validación en tu form `AsignarForm`, de la siguiente manera:

```
class AsignarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    # validamos el campo "materia"
    def clean_materia(self):
        # Obtenermos los datos del form
        docente = self.cleaned_data.get('docente')
        materia = self.cleaned_data.get('materia')

        # Si existe una instancia con el mismo docente y materia entramos al if
        if Asignar.objects.filter(docente_id = docente.id, materia_id = materia.id).exists():
            # Mandamos un error al form con un mensaje
            raise forms.ValidationError('No se puede asignar la misma materia a un docente 2 veses')
```

Puedes hacer esta validación también en tu vista pero es mejor hacerlo en el form. 
Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas Gracias me sirvió de mucho

Comment: Recuerda marcar como aceptada mi respuesta, si resolvio tu problema, marcando el check en forma de visto al costado de esta. :)